# Find all maximal ideals of the ring $\mathbb Z[i]$ containing the ideal $I=(4-2i) \mathbb Z[i] + (9+3i) \mathbb Z[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Find all maximal ideals of the ring $\mathbb Z[i]$ containing the ideal $I=(4-2i) \mathbb Z[i] + (9+3i) \mathbb Z[i]$

I think that in this task I need to find gcd first:
$$4-2i=2(2-i)=(1-i)(1+i)(2-i)$$
$$9+3i=3(3+i)=3(1+i)(2-i)$$
$$\text{gcd}(4-2i,9+3i) ∼ (1+i)(2-i)=3+i$$

However, I don't know what I can do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a PID. In a PID, to divide is to contain. Thus $(1+i)(2-i)=3+i$ gives
$$
\langle 1+i \rangle \supseteq \langle 3+i \rangle,
\quad
\langle 2-i \rangle \supseteq \langle 3+i \rangle
$$

Comment: Ok, so to sum up - the full procedure in this task is as follows: 1) we are looking for $\text{gcd}(4-2i,9+3i)$ and geting $3+i$ 2) thanks to $\text{gcd}$ we know that $I$ is generated by $3+i$: $I=\langle 3+i \rangle$ 3) using the fact the $\mathbb Z[i]$ is PID we know that: a is irreducible element in PID $\Leftrightarrow aR$ maximal ideal in PID 4) knowing that $\langle 1+i \rangle \supseteq \langle 3+i \rangle,
\quad
\langle 2-i \rangle \supseteq \langle 3+i \rangle$ and using 3) we have that solution are $I_1=\langle 2-i \rangle, I_2= \langle 1+i \rangle$.

Comment: Is it correct? Did I understand everything correctly?

Comment: @timofiej8384, yes, exactly. But you must argue that $\langle 1+i \rangle$ and $\langle 2-i \rangle$ are maximal ideals. Not hard, since you know all the divisors of $ 3+i$.